# Scala, Circe, Http4s - is it any way to encode Throwable in Circe?

Tags: json, scala, circe, http4s, zio

I have created hierarchy of errors:

```
sealed trait MyError extends Throwable
final case class SecondError(msg: String) extends MyError
```

Now I could get this kind of error in my `http4s` routes:

```
case GET -> Root / "things" => for {
        response <- things.all.foldM(
          error => error match {
            case SecondError(_) => InternalServerError(error)            
          }
...
```

But I get compiled error:

`could not find implicit value for parameter encoder: io.circe.Encoder[Throwable]`

Is it possible to encode `Throwable` with `circe` and `http4s`? I tried to do it this way:

```
implicit def encoderHttpThrowable: EntityEncoder[Env, Throwable] = jsonEncoderOf[Env, Throwable]
```

But it did not solve a problem.

Comment: From memory you don't have your `MyError` trait extend `Throwable` but instead match the `Throwable` to one of your `MyError`s. Then you just need to encode the error's case class

Comment: You mean extend Error instead of Throwable? What if functions I use need Throwable in signature?

Comment: At the "end of the world" you have a function of `Throwable => MyError` and then circe encodes the result of that

Comment: Here is an article which deals with this: https://typelevel.org/blog/2018/08/25/http4s-error-handling-mtl.html

Comment: I have encoders for my custom errors. The problem is only with Throwable

Comment: What type is `InternalServerError` exactly: `org.http4s.dsl.impl.InternalServerError`?

Comment: Yes, it is clear Status code from http4s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to encode automatically a Java Hierarchy with *Circe* (or any other library) (I am pretty sure of this).

So you have 3 possibilities:

1. Just use the Message of the error:

   ```
   case GET -> Root / "things"  =>
       things.all.foldM (
         error => InternalServerError(error.getMessage()),
         Ok(_)
       )
   ```
2. Or get rid of the Throwable:

   ```
     sealed trait MyError
     final case class SecondError(msg: String) extends MyError
   ```

   And now you can encode the error

   ```
   ...
   case GET -> Root / "things"  =>
     things.all.foldM (
       error => InternalServerError(error),
       Ok(_)
     )
   ```
3. Map your Throwable to your own Error (Sealed Trait without Throwable):

   ```
   ...
   case GET -> Root / "things"  =>
     things.all
       .mapError{
         case ex: IllegalArgumentException => SecondError(ex.getMessage)
         case ex => FirstError(ex.getMessage)
      }
       .foldM (
       error => InternalServerError(error),
       Ok(_)
     )
   ```

Comment: The problem here is that my functions `things.all` return `ZIO[Any, Throwable, Data]`, so the second solution is not possible to use. I'll try with first one.

Comment: Yet another possibility;) check my answer

Comment: Thanks, I have done some magic and also remove Throwable from extend and it work.